# Instruments fail to load after upgrading XCode from 7.0 to 7.01

Tags: xcode, instruments

Running OS X 10.10.5, I just upgrade XCode from version 7.0 to 7.01, but now Instruments will no longer run. I get this crash report:

```
Process:               Instruments [1521]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Instruments
Version:               ???
Build Info:            Instruments-58157000000000000~9
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Instruments [1521]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-09 08:59:30.085 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        47EAEE71-1B1D-E2BA-3A67-2F1ECE8F6C09


Time Awake Since Boot: 65000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1088D3000, size=0x004CF000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation

Binary Images:
    0x7fff64ed7000 -     0x7fff64f0d887  dyld (353.2.3) <B1B370A5-479F-3533-8AD7-97B687D4F989> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff825bb000 -     0x7fff825bbfff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.8 - 21) <EAC0EA1E-3C62-3B28-A941-5D8B1E085FF8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff82927000 -     0x7fff8292afff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <A95A15CD-3B21-3513-AFF8-1D7DE3DBFA12> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff871ad000 -     0x7fff87423ff7  com.apple.security (7.0 - 57031.40.6) <FCCCC4FD-043A-30CA-9997-4211CA0E9297> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff88d0b000 -     0x7fff88d0cfff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib

Model: Macmini5,1, BootROM MM51.0077.B12, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.76f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313333334B534E2D3447202020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313333334B534E2D3447202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: SanDisk SDSSDH2128G, 128,04 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPad
USB Device: Hub in Apple Pro Keyboard
USB Device: Microsoft Notebook/Mobile Optical Mouse 2.0
USB Device: Apple Pro Keyboard
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 22.2
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting the Mac solved the problem...

I must have been a Mac user for too long - in Windows it would be natural to reboot as soon as anything did not work :-)